# index vector that fit tensor at runtime using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensor

I've got this python function that uses **Tensorflow framework**:

```
def compute_ap(gain_vector):

    #this vector must fit the dimension of the gain_vector
    index_vector = tf.range(1, gain_vector.get_shape()[0],dtype=tf.float32)

    ap = tf.div(tf.reduce_sum(tf.div(tf.cast(gain_vector,tf.float32), index_vector), 1),tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(gain_vector,tf.float32), 1))
    return ap
```

when i run the program i get this error:

```
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype int32: 'Tensor("inputs/strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)'
```

seems that **gain_vector.get_shape()[0]** doesn't get the vector of the gain vector, what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.range()` accepts arguments only of type `int32`.

> Args:
>    start: A 0-D (scalar) of type `int32`. First entry in sequence.
>      Defaults to 0.

So, you could just create an `int32` tensor and cast it to `float32` later on. So, use something like this:

```
In [80]: index_vector = tf.range(1, tf.shape(gain_vector)[0])
In [81]: vec_float32 = tf.cast(index_vector, dtype=tf.float32)
```